# What is the difference between RXJS and Socket.io

Tags: typescript, socket.io, angular6, rxjs6

Am going to start working with RXJS and socket io in Angular 6+ but before that I want to know whether this both are same or in a different case. Can anybody assist me in where to use these both in Angular?

Comment: they are both really different things. RxJs is a streaming library for asyncrhonous execution of stuff. (subjects, observables, ...)  and Websockets are a way to communicate between the client and server. It means that your client and server stay connected, which is different from traditional (rest) web services.

Comment: you may also want to look into socket-io , which is a wrapper around websockets and provides better compatibility and more rebust connections.

Comment: do I want to use Rxjs for Getting data from the server in real-time, Suppose I want to implement a Line Graph that Plots the Network Traffic in Live?

Comment: If you want real-time information, then you certainly need websockets, you don't want to poll your server using traditional rest APIs. ;  Next, the question is how you will distribute them within your application. And that is where RxJs can help you.  RxJs provides classes like Subject , which you can register to as a listener. Angular and RxJs are good friends, so using RxJs is certainly the way to go.

Comment: to be honest, I think you may want to get some experience with async programming in angular first . e.g. use promises, work with async pipes, some subjects ... and when you master those, read something like: https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/

Comment: @JBNizet, I know Rxjs is not a networking protocol and am sorry I used WebSocket in my question heading that's why you got confused, I just replaced it with socket io. and while I went through some of the videos on youtube I got stuck with the concept of socket.io and Rxjs, someone used Socket io for creating chat apps in angular and some used Rxjs :(  really got confused.

Comment: Again, you're comparing apples and oranges. You can use socket.io or WebSockets with or without RxJS. RxJS is just a JS library allowing to deal with asynchronous events.

Comment: @JBNizet, maybe I need to learn those things in deep to avoid getting in these kinds of blunders

Comment: @bvdb ok ill go through this link and learn more about these topics

Comment: @bvdb  now I realize what things go around, thank you for your tutorials , happy codeing

Answer (score 5):

I researched and learned a lot from the internet about this topic, Now I realize **RXJS** is a simple library for reactive programming and **Websocket** is a realtime web service.